# wordexp and strings with spaces

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to expand variables in a `string` that contains a unix file path. For example the string is:

```
std::string path = "$HOME/Folder  With  Two  Spaces  Next  To  Each  Other".
```

This is my code for `wordexp` I use:

```
#include <wordexp.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string env_subst(const std::string &path)
{
        std::string result = "";
        wordexp_t p;
        if (!::wordexp(path.c_str(), &p, 0))
        {
                if (p.we_wordc >= 1)
                {
                        result = std::string(p.we_wordv[0]);
                        for (uint32_t i = 1; i < p.we_wordc; ++i)
                        {
                                result += " " + std::string(p.we_wordv[i]);
                        }
                }
                ::wordfree(&p);
                return result;
        }
        else
        {
                // Illegal chars found
                return path;
        }
}

int main()
{
        std::string teststring = "$HOME/Folder  With  Two  Spaces  Next  To  Each  Other";
        std::string result = env_subst(teststring);
        std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Result: /home/nidhoegger/Folder With Two Spaces Next To Each Other
```

You see, that whereas there were two spaces between the words in the input, there is now only a single space.

Is there an easy way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code removes the double spaces in your path is because your for loop adds only a single space after every word, regardless of the actual number of spaces. A possible solution to this problem would be to locate all the spaces in your path string beforehand, and then add them in. For example, you could use something like this:

```
std::string spaces[p.we_wordc];
uint32_t pos = path.find(" ", 0);
uint32_t j=0;

while(pos!=std::string::npos){

    while(path.at(pos)==' '){
    spaces[j]+=" ";
    pos++;
    }

    pos=path.find(" ", pos+1);
    j++;
}
```

to iterate through your path using std::string::find and store the spaces in a string array. Then, you could modify the line in your for loop to

```
result += spaces[i-1] + std::string(p.we_wordv[i]);
```

to add in the appropriate number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve spaces in an unusually named file, enclose it in braces: `std::string teststring = "\"~/filename  with   spaces\"";`. But it doesn't make sense to note how many spaces there were in an original string, since you'll have to skip pairs of `"` and basically redo what `wordexp()` does. Leaving multiple spaces in a command doesn't make much sense: `ls -al` is exactly the same as `ls   -al`, so the trimming is justified. And the OP's code is perfectly valid -- no need to add anything else.

P.S. Decided to add this as a note because I fell in the same pit as OP.